# Getting Started with EC2 Container Registry

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, docker-compose, dockerhub

This is giving me a headache.

Here's what I've done so far

- Created an EC2 Virtual Server Instance, and its running
- Installed the AWS CLI
- Installed Docker on my EC2 Virtual Server after I SSH'd into it

So looking at the docs it tells you how to build an image.  Now comes my confusion.

**Question 1**: So am I right by assuming that one basically have an option to **a)** build an image off your host or **b)** pull an image created by others from Docker Hub?

**Question 2**: If I'm right about Question #1 then what am I building an image ** off of** if I am not pulling one from docker hub? with the AWS docs here?

**Question 3**: then I see a whole different route I can take, using Docker Compose, so I'd use that instead of all this above?  This is so confusing.

[EC2 Container Registry – Now Generally Available](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/ec2-container-registry-now-generally-available/)

So again, [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-basics.html#docker_hub_create_upload), it tells you to install docker on the Host.  Then immediately jumps into "create an image".  Create an image off what, that host's OS?  I don't get it, I guess that's what it means OR I can pull an image from Docker Hub and not go this route?

Same [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html), it's talking about creating a docker image, **what** off the Host?

Or..maybe I'm not understanding what "image" means but I assume going this route, instead of pulling a Docker image from Docker Hub that I'm creating an image off my EC2 virtual Instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A1**: No. You can't build an image off your host. 
You can create an new image according to your requirement like which Operating Sytem (Ubuntu, Fedora), Stack(LAMP, LEMP) and many other things.
Or you can pull an image which will be pre-configured with all the packages like Wordpress Stack image, Magento stack image, Bitnami image which you can pull from docker-hub.

**A2**: As I have mentioned earlier you can build an image of any operating system you want(Ubuntu, Fedora, Debian) but not off the host. 
You just need to pull image from docker-hub. e.g `docker pull ubuntu` will pull mininmal image of Ubuntu-14.04. And if you need specific version of Ubuntu
like Ubuntu-12.04 version e.g `docker pull ubuntu:12.04` will pull minimal image of Ubuntu-12.04

**A3**: Docker-compose is a tool for defining and running multi-container docker applications. docker-compose conatins a compose file 
in which you can configure your application services.

And finally Amazon EC2 Container Registry is little bit different thing. The Idea is the same as docker but Amazon is providing
this as a EC2 Container Service with many other functionality which docker doesn't have right now.

Hope it hepls:-)